# Changing QLineEdit with the push of a button

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to do now is find a way to increment the QLineEdit box (Step_Box) with the corresponding value of one of the buttons (0.01, 1, 10...). Each time I press on one of the buttons, the entry on QLineEdit must increment by that value. How should I do this?

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QGridLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLineEdit,
    QLabel,
    QComboBox,
)

class XY_Buttons(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(XY_Buttons, self).__init__()

        self.clicked.connect(self.is_clicked)
        self.setText(str(name))

    def is_clicked(self):
        print("A")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Suruga Controller")

        OuterLayout = QGridLayout() # Parent layout
        ArrowsLayout = QGridLayout() # Arrows layout -- in here are the XY controller
        UpDownLayout = QGridLayout() # Up and Down layout -- z controller
        XYLayout = QGridLayout() # XY options layout -- step size and others
        ZLayout = QGridLayout() # Z options layout -- step size and others

        # Adding Widgets for ArrowsLayout
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Up"), 0, 1)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Down"), 2, 1)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Left"), 1, 0)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Right"), 1, 2)

        # Adding Widgets for XYLayout
        xstep=0.0
        Step_Box = QLineEdit(str(xstep))
        Step_Box.setReadOnly(True)
        Units_Box = QComboBox()
        Units_Box.addItems([u"10E-6 (µm) ", "10E-3 (cm)"])
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(0.01), 1, 0)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(0.1), 1, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(1), 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(10), 2, 0)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(100), 2, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(1000), 2, 2)
    #    XYLayout.addWidget(Clear_Button(), 0, 2, 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Step is:"), 0, 0, 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(Step_Box, 0, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(Units_Box, 3, 1)

        # Nesting all layouts
        OuterLayout.addLayout(ArrowsLayout, 0, 0)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(XYLayout, 0, 1)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(UpDownLayout, 1, 0)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(ZLayout, 1, 1)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(OuterLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

[image: Screenshot of the application]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some reference to the instance of `QLineEdit` i.e. `Step_Box` in order to change their values from the button click, since you have  a custom button class, you can just pass the instance of the line edit and store it there, then you can just increment the value from the slot to which you have connected the `clicked` signal of the buttons.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QGridLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLineEdit,
    QLabel,
    QComboBox,
)

class XY_Buttons(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, name, lineEdit:QLineEdit=None):
        super(XY_Buttons, self).__init__()

        self.clicked.connect(self.is_clicked)
        self.setText(str(name))
        self.lineEdit = lineEdit

    def is_clicked(self):
        print("A")
        self.lineEdit.setText(str(float(self.lineEdit.text())+ float(self.text())))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Suruga Controller")

        OuterLayout = QGridLayout() # Parent layout
        ArrowsLayout = QGridLayout() # Arrows layout -- in here are the XY controller
        UpDownLayout = QGridLayout() # Up and Down layout -- z controller
        XYLayout = QGridLayout() # XY options layout -- step size and others
        ZLayout = QGridLayout() # Z options layout -- step size and others

        # Adding Widgets for ArrowsLayout
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Up"), 0, 1)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Down"), 2, 1)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Left"), 1, 0)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Right"), 1, 2)

        # Adding Widgets for XYLayout
        xstep=0.0
        Step_Box = QLineEdit(str(xstep))
        Step_Box.setReadOnly(True)
        Units_Box = QComboBox()
        Units_Box.addItems([u"10E-6 (µm) ", "10E-3 (cm)"])
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(0.01, Step_Box), 1, 0)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(0.1, Step_Box), 1, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(1, Step_Box), 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(10, Step_Box), 2, 0)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(100, Step_Box), 2, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(XY_Buttons(1000, Step_Box), 2, 2)
    #    XYLayout.addWidget(Clear_Button(), 0, 2, 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Step is:"), 0, 0, 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(Step_Box, 0, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(Units_Box, 3, 1)

        # Nesting all layouts
        OuterLayout.addLayout(ArrowsLayout, 0, 0)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(XYLayout, 0, 1)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(UpDownLayout, 1, 0)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(ZLayout, 1, 1)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(OuterLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

But generally, passing reference like this is not considered a good practice, so  it'd have been better if you connected it from within the class where the instance was created.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to introduce a clear separation of the data, i.e. the currently selected step, from the GUI. A common approach is Model-View-Controller (MVC).
I think it is necessary for any GUI application, as it otherwise leads to spaghetti code of *widgets* talking to each other, patching out bugs.

There are several View and Model components already available inside Qt5 (QStringListModel + QListView for example), but it's trivial to make our own.

Here I introduce the `FooModel` and the corresponding view, along with buttons (Controller) that attempts to modify the model.

```py
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QGridLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLineEdit,
    QLabel,
    QComboBox,
)


class FooChanger(QPushButton):
    # Note: This is the controller. It doesn't try to be clever and modify the view.
    # It just modifies the model. If the model wishes to signal to any view component, that's the models responsibility.
    
    def __init__(self, foo_model, value):
        super().__init__(str(value))
        self.clicked.connect(self.is_clicked)
        self.model = foo_model
        self.value = value
 
    def is_clicked(self):
        self.model.set_value(self.value)

        
class FooView(QLabel):
    # This is the view. It does try to be clever either. It just updates information when the model signals.
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__("hejsan")
        self.model = model
        self.model.data_changed.connect(self.refresh)
        self.refresh() # initial refresh
    
    def refresh(self):
        self.setText(str(self.model.value))


class FooModel(QObject):
    # This is our simple model. It only has a signal, and uses it to indicate when the data has been modified.
    # Make sure to use the set_value function and don't poke at self.value directly!
    data_changed = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, initial_value):
        super().__init__()
        # We are currently just storing one piece of information. The infamous Foo value!
        self.value = initial_value

    def set_value(self, new_value):
        self.value = new_value
        self.data_changed.emit()

        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Suruga Controller")

        OuterLayout = QGridLayout() # Parent layout
        ArrowsLayout = QGridLayout() # Arrows layout -- in here are the XY controller
        UpDownLayout = QGridLayout() # Up and Down layout -- z controller
        XYLayout = QGridLayout() # XY options layout -- step size and others
        ZLayout = QGridLayout() # Z options layout -- step size and others

        # Adding Widgets for ArrowsLayout
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Up"), 0, 1)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Down"), 2, 1)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Left"), 1, 0)
        ArrowsLayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Right"), 1, 2)

        # Adding Widgets for XYLayout
        step_box = FooView(model)
        unix_box = QComboBox()
        unix_box.addItems([u"10E-6 (µm) ", "10E-3 (cm)"])
        XYLayout.addWidget(FooChanger(model, 0.01), 1, 0)
        XYLayout.addWidget(FooChanger(model, 0.1), 1, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(FooChanger(model, 1), 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(FooChanger(model, 10), 2, 0)
        XYLayout.addWidget(FooChanger(model, 100), 2, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(FooChanger(model, 1000), 2, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Step is:"), 0, 0, 1, 2)
        XYLayout.addWidget(step_box, 0, 1)
        XYLayout.addWidget(unix_box, 3, 1)

        # Nesting all layouts
        OuterLayout.addLayout(ArrowsLayout, 0, 0)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(XYLayout, 0, 1)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(UpDownLayout, 1, 0)
        OuterLayout.addLayout(ZLayout, 1, 1)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(OuterLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
foo = FooModel(3.1415)
window = MainWindow(foo) # The view acts on our foo.
window.show()
app.exec()
```

There is no need for cross-talk between *widgets* here. It's just a view that only displays current data (it doesn't even care how the data got modified, it just always works), a controller that just informs the model that the user requested a change, and a model that is blissfully ignorant of the existence of either widgets or buttons.

Comment: "I think it is necessary for any GUI application, as it otherwise leads to spaghetti code or widgets talking to each other, patching out bugs." Qt objects *do* talk to each other, that's exactly what signals/slots are for: the communication is based on compatible signals that would specifically avoid "bugs", avoiding in the meantime unnecessary layers. The MVC is an important pattern that should always be considered, but not arbitrarily used without proper evaluation and analysis of benefits and drawbacks. In this specific case, creating a "model" for a simple variable is IMHO an overshoot.

Comment: The state in the question consisted of a single number to demonstrate the concept on. Having the state of your program stored in text fields inside widgets is never a good design and I think it's important to always guide new users away from such a mistake. MVC fits perfectly well even for simpler programs.

Comment: It's always important to guide new users into using methods, practices and patterns with *awareness*. A beginner would hardly understand the real differences in concepts and context of a "state" of a program against a variable "stored" in a widget (which, conceptually, is a small and self contained MV pattern): to them, they are almost the same thing. The problem of suggesting a *good* (but not absolute) practice in a generic context is that the user might not understand the requirement, and might be led to believe that this should be done in *any* case. Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying ->

Comment: ->that yours is a bad suggestion. But I believe it should be given by ensuring that it's properly understood and that readers become aware of the requirement; that's why I don't completely agree with "it is necessary for any GUI application": I've seen a lot of cases of beginners struggling because they used an MVC pattern on their programs, as they were told that it was "good practice", but there was no benefit in using it on those programs (there was no *formal* "model"), with the result that they didn't understand what they were doing wrong and were just *very* (and unnecessarily) confused.

Comment: Well OK, I just don't think never nudging them in the direction of this separation leads to code where business logic and state is deeply nested into the view, with "controllers" and "views" haphazardly referencing each other to the point where the code is salvageable.

Comment: Those are very important aspects, but they also require both profound studying, understanding and awareness that can rarely be properly summarized in a concise (and in this case, fundamentally unrelated) answer with enough insights, while ensuring that they become aware of the base concept and its ramifications. Most of us try as much as possible to not only provide answers, but *teach something* in the meantime, but we're not "teachers" here on SO, we're most consultants. There's no "learning path" through unique answers, and some suggestions, even if correct, might lead to unwanted results.

Comment: I'll just have to respectfully disagree. I believe this is related, as it essentially about how the "control" affect the "view" even if the OP didn't know it was. I just don't believe doing C->M->V (as opposed to C->V) is some dangerous tool that may only be wielded after years of careful deliberation, rather just gluing together what the question present is what often leads to unwanted results (given that the accepted answer even suggest that it isn't good practice).